# Can't show date difference in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, mobile-browser

In my application I need to calculate age of persons for this I am getting current date and their birthdays in miliseconds. Calculating difference of dates and converting it to years

```
$scope.getAge=function(birthday){
if (birthday!=undefined&&birthday!="") {
  var date = birthday.split('-');
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var convertedBD= new Date(date[1]+"-"+date[0]+"-"+date[2]);
  var diff = Math.abs(currentDate-convertedBD)/(1000*60*60*24*365);
  return Math.round(diff);
}
else {
  return "0";
}}
```

This works perfectly on desktop browser and mobile preview in Google Chrome but when I test it on real mobile device it shows NaN for every value. I couldn't figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .getTime(), which explicitly asks for the milliseconds portion of the Date:

```
 var diff = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - convertedBD.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24*365);
```

Try this for the parsing:

```
if (birthday!=undefined&&birthday!="") {
   var date = birthday.split('-');
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var convertedBD= new Date( parseInt(date[2]), parseInt(date[1]), parseInt(date[0]) );
   var diff = Math.abs(currentDate-convertedBD)/(1000*60*60*24*365);
   return Math.round(diff);
```

}

Comment: Now it is working fine on Android but problem still continues in iphone I tried Google Chrome on iphone too.

Comment: Working like a charm !